# Debugging TypeScript Renderer in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, electron

I am able to launch the Electron main app and to set breakpoints in the TypeScript source. I can also attach the Renderer process. But when I set a breakpoint Renderer process (actually in preload.ts), VS Code displays the transpiled JavaScript when stopping. I guess this is about these three config files:

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Electron: Main",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": ["--remote-debugging-port=9223", "./bin"],
            "outputCapture": "std"
        },
        {
            "name": "Electron: Renderer",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9223,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "timeout": 30000,
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Electron: All",
            "configurations": ["Electron: Main", "Electron: Renderer"]
        }
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "bin",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hello_world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc && copyfiles -f src/index.html bin",
    "start": "npm run compile && electron ./bin",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "electron": "^12.0.7",
    "rxjs": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what the issue is without a lot more information. Are you bundling your js? First thing I'd try is to enable inline sourcemaps with your bundler. This way the maps are more easily found...

Comment: No, no bundling. Pretty much Electron's vanialla project: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start